# Issue setting callback results equal to object properties (node-tesseract)

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, callback, tesseract

I'm trying to use the results of a callback function as properties of an object. Here is how I am trying to use the module I am building:

```html
var Screenshot = require("./Screenshot.js")

const test = async function() {
    let screenshot = new Screenshot("./screenshots/Screenshot_20180806093446.jpg")
    await screenshot.readScreenshot()
    console.log(screenshot.text)
}

test() // logs nothing to console
```

readScreenshot() doesn't seem to be doing its job. I'm sure there's a finer detail I am missing to making this work.

./Screenshot.js code below:

```html
var tesseract = require("node-tesseract");

module.exports = class Screenshot {
  constructor(path) {
    this.path = path;
    this.readScreenshot = this.readScreenshot.bind(this);
  }
  readScreenshot() {
    tesseract.process(this.path, (err, text) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        this.text = text.split("\n").filter(el => el.trim() !== "");
      }
    });
  }
};
```

It would also be nice if I can get the constructor of class Screenshot to properly call this function so I do not have to do it manually in app.js

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the code so that `readScreenshot` method allows you to return a promise object.

```
readScreenshot() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    tesseract.process(this.path, (err, text) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(text.split("\n").filter(el => el.trim() !== ""))
      }
    });
  });
}
```

//

```
var Screenshot = require("./Screenshot.js")

const test = async function() {
    let screenshot = new Screenshot("./screenshots/Screenshot_20180806093446.jpg")
    let resp = await screenshot.readScreenshot()
    console.log(resp)
}

test() // logs nothing to console
```

Comment: You are missing `this.text = text.split("\n").filter(el => el.trim() !== "");` before or after calling resolve. Since this is an object instance the value might also be needed there.

Comment: @ErickRuizdeChavez I don't see the `text` being used anywhere else other than the log statement.  So just returned as part of the resolution instead of setting it on the instance. But ya, it can be set on the instance as well before we resolve it